# Left join and select the next observation in time in R

Tags: r, time, tidyverse, tidyr, xts

Suppose I have two dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("Ana", "Lola", "Ana"),
             Date=c("2020-06-06", "2020-06- 06", "2020-06- 07"),
             meat=c("fish", "poultry", "poultry"),
             time_ordered=c("2020-06-06 12:24:39", "2020-06-06 12:34:36", "2020-06-07 12:24:39"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c("Ana","Ana",  "Lola", "Ana"),
             Date=c("2020-06-06", "2020-06-06",  "2020-06- 06", "2020-06- 07"),
             meat=c("fish", "fish", "poultry", "poultry"),
             time_received=c("2020-06-06 12:24:40", "2020-06-06 12:26:49",  "2020-06-07 12:36:39", "2020-06-07 13:04:39"))
```

Suppose I want to join these two dataframes on ID and meat.
Then, for a given observation, I want to match time_ordered with the first time_received following it.
For instance, I should have a row "ID = Ana, Data=  2020-06-06, Meat = fish, time_ordered = 2020-06-06 12:24:39, time received = 2020-06-06 12:24:40".

So I would not matched the time_received "2020-06-06 12:26:49" with anything.
In fact for each (ID, Meat, time_observed), i want to match uniquely to (ID, Meat, min(time_received) > time_observed)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join `df` by `df2` by `ID`, `meat` and `Date`, keep only the rows where `time_received >  time_ordered` arrange the data by `time_received` and keep only unique rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('ID', 'meat', 'Date')) %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date), 
         across(c(time_ordered, time_received), ymd_hms)) %>%
  filter(time_received >  time_ordered) %>%
  arrange(ID, Date, meat, time_received) %>%
  distinct(ID, Date, meat, .keep_all = TRUE)

#    ID       Date    meat        time_ordered       time_received
#1  Ana 2020-06-06    fish 2020-06-06 12:24:39 2020-06-06 12:24:40
#2  Ana 2020-06-07 poultry 2020-06-07 12:24:39 2020-06-07 13:04:39
#3 Lola 2020-06-06 poultry 2020-06-06 12:34:36 2020-06-07 12:36:39
```